# C# WPF Application runs in VS Debug but not as a EXE

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, crash

I have a strange Problem. I wrote a C# WPF Application wיich runs perfectly in Visual Studio Debug. But when I start the EXE outside of Visual Studio (I didn't move the .exe it's still in the bin\Debug Folder) the Main Window is displayed correctly and works, but if I try to open the second Window the App crashes. I start the .exe from a Networkdrive but that has always worked so far, this Problem started today. I have commented out all the major Changes I made but still the same Problem.
He copied the following Information into Temp:

```
<ParentProcessInformation>
    <ParentProcessId>3476</ParentProcessId>
    <ParentProcessPath>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</ParentProcessPath>
    <ParentProcessCmdLine>C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE</ParentProcessCmdLine>
</ParentProcessInformation>
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>zimk.kalender.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>53c4f986</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>PresentationFramework</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>3.0.0.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>5167b4d1</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>6263</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>e1</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

And the this Information I got from a .mdmp File:

> Exception Code: 0xE0434F4D
>   Exception Information: An exception came from CLR

Comment: same problem is you start as Administrator ?

Comment: Show us code for opening the second window and maybe what's on that window. If you can open the application and all the windows in VS without crashing, it sounds like your problem is missing references.  Make sure your non .NET Framework references `Copy Local` is set to `True`.

Comment: i think there some functionality is breaking. so what i would suggest.  handle dispatcherUnhandledExcpetion in app.xaml and log the exception in some physical location and you will be able to note down what exactly is the cause of errror.

Comment: Just a guess. Is the exe on a network share? If so copy it to local drive and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I use `Command Line Parameters` but forgot to start the exe with `Parameters`.
Sorry I wasted your Time.